# Update an object property in useState Hook,Property name should be get from a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, object

```
  const [fee, setFee] = useState({newPatient:'',establishedPatient:''})

  const field1='newPatient'        
  const field2='establishedPatient'
```

I want to update the fee object properties. Property name should be taken from variables (field1,field 2)

```
   onChangeText={(val)=>setFee({...fee,newPatient:val})}. //Working
   onChangeText={(val)=>setFee({...fee,...fee[field1]=val})} //Here I'm using field 1 variable to get the property name and its not working
```

[image: expected result]
[image: Here i can see 2 more properties 0,1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want

```
onChangeText={(val)=>setFee({...fee, [field1]: val })}
```